# Why use apostrophe-s to denote possession when using 'of'

Tags: possessives, double-possessive

Think of the simple phrase "Bill's friend".

If you were going to turn this around using the preposition 'of' would you say:

- A friend of Bill's
  or
- A friend of Bill

It appears to me that, in the US anyway, people always say "A friend of Bill's".

Even though I'm a native American English speaker, this just sounds weird to me. It seems to create a 'double possessive' (a term I just invented). I always want to respond: "A friend of Bill's what?" A friend of Bill's aunt?

So what's at work here, and do British English speakers also do this?

Comment: Good question.  Like the "A friend of Bill's *what*?".  Of course, I'm not sure there *is* an answer... quite a lot of language is "because it has evolved that way".  Language *is* weird.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As @FX_ points out, it’s called a **[double genitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_possessive#Double_genitive)** or **double possessive**.

In this example, it’s not compulsory: both *a friend of Bill’s* and *a friend of Bill* are correct, although the first is probably more common.  (Usage data, anyone?)

If Bill were replaced by a pronoun, however (poor Bill!), the double genitive would be required: *a friend of mine* is correct, but not *a friend of me*.  (Similarly with *yours* vs. *you*, *his* vs. *he*, etc.)

Also, sometimes, this is needed to avoid ambiguity between the possessive and other uses of *of*: for instance, *a picture of Bill’s* means that he owns the picture, whereas *a picture of Bill* means he’s portrayed in it.

Comment: Replacing Bill with a pronoun really does provide some clarity. I also had not considered 'a picture of Bill's' vs. 'a picture of Bill'. In that case the need for a double possessive is really clear. Well answered!

Comment: There is a _huge_ difference between "a picture of his" and "a picture of him".

Comment: In the Wikipedia link there is no mention of "double genitive", I reckon the page has since been updated.

Answer (score 7):

The correct form is *“a friend of Bill’s”*, and it's called a [**double genitive**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genitive_case#Double_genitive) (see also [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/double%20genitive)).

Comment: Interestingly, Merriam-Webster says it's *also* called "double possessive". :D

Comment: You are correct that this is a double genitive, but is the double genitive form really the only one that can be considered correct?

Comment: I guess I'm not as smart as I thought. I should have googled 'double possessive' before I claimed to have invented it :)

Comment: I think it's too early to anoint "A friend of Bill's" as the 'correct' form. Seems to me that "Mark is a friend of Bill" sounds perfectly correct, and perfectly equivalent to "Mark is Bill's friend", while "Mark is a friend of Bill's" leaves us hanging semantically close to "Mark is a friend of Bill's mother" without actually going there. In fact, I would propose that "Mark is a friend of Bill's" is ambiguous in a purely grammatical sense.

Comment: @adj7388: "Mark is a friend of Bill's" should be understood as "Mark is one friend out of all of Bill's friends", or just "Mark is one of Bill's friends".

Comment: In the first link you posted there is no mention of "double genitive" I reckon the page has since been updated.